# Deploying a GWT web application on Github

Tags: github, gwt, web-applications

Can a GWT web application be deployed on Github?

For example, a GWT web application is created, and it works on a server intalled with Tomcat. It's known that a web page can be created on Github, like http://help.github.com/articles/creating-pages-with-the-automatic-generator/ Can a GWT web application also be deployed on Github? If it's possible, how to deploy it?

Comment: Maybe GAE is an option for you (http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/appengine.html )

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Github Pages you can only use/host client-side technology like JavaScript, CSS and HTML. So your app would not have an back-end which can handle your RPCs. But it's possible on GitHub Pages to make Ajax calls (http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/code-a-simple-github-api-webapp-using-jquery-ajax ) , which are also the base for GWT-RPCs.

When the fron-end is running, you need a server for your backend. Afaik there are libraries to use php as an back-end (I guess most are not maintained anymore), or you could use the [JsonpRequestBuilder](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/jsonp/client/JsonpRequestBuilder.html) to make HTTP-calls to a server of your choice. JSONP would be necessary to overcome the cross-domain restrictions imposed by browsers [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), because your backend would be on a different server.

So all in all this is not the way to go. As I mentioned in the comments you can try the GAE ([Google App Engine](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/appengine.html)) to host your application without recreating your back-end, because the other solution would require to rewrite your back-end (eg. PHP) and to host it somewhere

**One last tip: Before you move definitely to GAE, check that you have all necessary [libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/) for you backed.**

Answer (score -1):

If you are using servlets and stuff : certainly no

If you are only using client stuff, my guess is also no. I don't think github even allows javascript, or even html ?

Comment: Github does static HTML hosting. You just got to commit to the branch gh-pages. https://pages.github.com/